# Does this still happen in Haunt 16 even if the traitor dies?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

The traitor's instructions for haunt #16, "The Phantom's Embrace", reads:

> **You Must Do This On Your Turn**
>   At the end of each of your turns, advance the Turn/Damage Track to the next number. Then roll a number of dice equal to that number. The house blows up if you roll the following number or higher: [...]

If the explorers kill the traitor, does the track continue to advance each round? 
My playgroup was divided between two interpretations:

1. Dead players don't get a turn. The traitor is dead, so he/she no longer does anything 'at the end of each of your turns". **The house is no longer in danger of blowing up.**
2. Dead players do get a turn, but ordinarily can take no actions because a corpse can't move / use items / etc. But they can carry out special instructions like the one indicated in this haunt. And anyway, it makes more thematic sense that the bomb would continue to tick down even after the demise of the person that set it. **The house is still in danger of blowing up.**

Which is the correct interpretation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The house is still in danger of blowing up. The FAQ clarifies that the traitor still gets turns:

> A dead traitor can still move monsters, **etc., during his turn**.

If this weren't true, the heroes could usually pull off an easy win by killing the traitor and then taking their sweet time to scour the house for helpful items. This would be imbalanced, boring, and, as you mention, thematically inconsistent.